# ORA-00900 on delete statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ora-00900

I'm trying to use `DELETE FROM` with an `IN` clause and a subquery to delete rows given by a query on another table that is 1-to-1 with the table I am deleting from, but Oracle 11g2 barfs an utterly unhelpful ORA-00900 error at me, as in the following SQL fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93171/1

For those who can't get at SQLfiddle, the schema/initial load I'm using is (I'm using `varchar` instead of `varchar2` for test portability, the "wild" data uses `varchar2` instead):

```
create table obj (id integer primary key, data varchar(100));
create table meta(id integer primary key, imported char(1));

insert into obj (id, data) values (1, 'foo');
insert into obj (id, data) values (2, 'bar');
insert into obj (id, data) values (3, 'baz');
insert into obj (id, data) values (4, 'blurf');
insert into obj (id, data) values (5, 'hurf');
insert into meta (id, imported) values (1, 'T');
insert into meta (id, imported) values (2, 'F');
insert into meta (id, imported) values (3, 'T');
insert into meta (id, imported) values (4, 'F');
insert into meta (id, imported) values (5, 'F');
```

and the statements I'm trying to run are:

```
delete from obj where obj.id in (select meta.id from meta where meta.imported = 'F');
select * from obj full outer join meta on obj.id = meta.id;
```

(The `select ... full outer join` runs by itself, and the error still happens if I still comment it out, so it's not the source of the ORA-00900.)

P.S. this statement is valid SQL, too -- neither SQL Server 2014  nor PostgreSQL 9.3 have an issue with the fiddle, and it works in a local copy of SQLite 3.8.8.3 as well once the `full outer join` is switched for an `inner join`.

Comment: Might be a bug in SQLFiddle, runs okay on my local Oracle, version `Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production`.

Comment: Your SQL Fiddle runs fine if the `delete` is on the left, in the schema definition.  Only `select` works on the right hand side. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0a120/2)

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- bizarre, I suppose it's either a bug in SQLFiddle indeed or an undocumented restriction...

Comment: @LThode . . . I think SQL Fiddle is pretty clear that data definition and modification code goes on the left and queries go on the right.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- not really, quoting their [about page](http://sqlfiddle.com/about.html): "MySQL only supports queries which read from the schema (selects, basically). This is necessary due to some limitations in MySQL that make it impossible for me to ensure a consistent schema while various people are fiddling with it. The other database options allow the full range of queries that the back-end supports. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed an issue in SQLFiddle -- the ORA-00900 does not occur when I run that form of delete statement against the actual database I'm working with.

Why the about page doesn't document this more clearly, I do not know...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a left join in union with  left join by reversing the table and take only null values

```
select * from obj left join meta on obj.id = meta.id 
union all
select * from meta left join obj  on obj.id = meta.id 
where obj.id is null
```